# Traefik returns 500 error after 30s requesting page

Tags: docker, oauth-2.0, traefik

I need your help with this issue.

I am setting an authentication service in docker swarm environment using Keycloak as a provider and OAuth2-proxy with `forwardauth` and `errors` middlewares. Actually, I set up these services for 3 servers a couple of months ago and they are working fine but when I try to set it up on a new server, I got 500 error HTTP.

There is no more log information about the error even I set traefik log level to DEBUG, when I looked at traefik look I only saw it.

```
14.168.51.149 - - [26/Sep/2022:04:29:09 +0000] "GET / HTTP/2.0" 500 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/105.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" 2412 "auth_testing@docker" "-" 30000ms
```

Also attach my configuration for my testing service and oauth:

```
  oauth:
    image: quay.io/oauth2-proxy/oauth2-proxy:v7.1.1
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints: [node.labels.web==web]
      labels:
        - "traefik.enable=true"
        - "traefik.http.routers.oauth.rule=Host(`oauth.${HOST_ABBR}.domain.org`) || PathPrefix(`/oauth2`)"
        - "traefik.http.routers.oauth.entrypoints=websecure"
        - "traefik.http.routers.oauth.tls=true"
        - "traefik.http.routers.oauth.tls.certresolver=leresolver"
        # Set up service
        - "traefik.http.routers.oauth.service=oauth@docker"
        - "traefik.http.services.oauth.loadbalancer.server.port=4185"
        # Set up middlewares
        - 'traefik.http.middlewares.oauth.forwardauth.address=https://oauth.${HOST_ABBR}.doamin.org/oauth2/auth'
        - 'traefik.http.middlewares.oauth.forwardauth.trustForwardHeader=true'
        - 'traefik.http.middlewares.oauth.forwardauth.authResponseHeaders=X-Auth-Request-User, X-Auth-Request-Groups, X-Auth-Request-Email, X-Auth-Request-Preferred-Username, X-Auth-Request-Access-Token'
        - "traefik.http.middlewares.oauth-signin.errors.service=oauth@docker"
        - "traefik.http.middlewares.oauth-signin.errors.status=401,403"
        - "traefik.http.middlewares.oauth-signin.errors.query=/oauth2/sign_in"
    environment:
      OAUTH2_PROXY_CLIENT_ID: 'coffee_authentication'
      OAUTH2_PROXY_CLIENT_SECRET: 'xxxxxxx99af13b51' 
      
      OAUTH2_PROXY_PROVIDER: 'keycloak'
      OAUTH2_PROXY_SCOPE: 'openid profile email'
      OAUTH2_PROXY_OIDC_ISSUER_URL: '${MY_DOMAIN}/auth/realms/coffee'
      OAUTH2_PROXY_LOGIN_URL: '${MY_DOMAIN}/auth/realms/coffee/protocol/openid-connect/auth'
      OAUTH2_PROXY_REDEEM_URL: '${MY_DOMAIN}/auth/realms/coffee/protocol/openid-connect/token'
      OAUTH2_PROXY_PROFILE_URL: '${MY_DOMAIN}/auth/realms/coffee/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo'
      OAUTH2_PROXY_VALIDATE_URL: '${MY_DOMAIN}/auth/realms/coffee/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo'
      
      OAUTH2_PROXY_PASS_ACCESS_TOKEN: 'true'
      OAUTH2_PROXY_PASS_USER_HEADERS: 'true'
      OAUTH2_PROXY_PASS_BASIC_AUTH: 'true'
      OAUTH2_PROXY_SET_XAUTHREQUEST: 'true'
      OAUTH2_PROXY_SET_AUTHORIZATION_HEADER: 'true'
      OAUTH2_PROXY_COOKIE_DOMAINS: '${MY_DOMAIN}'
      OAUTH2_PROXY_HTTP_ADDRESS: '0.0.0.0:4185'
      OAUTH2_PROXY_COOKIE_REFRESH: '12h'
      OAUTH2_PROXY_COOKIE_SECURE: 'false'
      # python -c 'import os,base64; print(base64.urlsafe_b64encode(os.urandom(32)).decode())'
      OAUTH2_PROXY_COOKIE_SECRET: '${SECRET_COOKIE}'
      OAUTH2_PROXY_AUTHENTICATED_EMAILS_FILE: '/oauth-conf/authorized_emails.txt'
      #OAUTH2_PROXY_EMAIL_DOMAINS: '*'
      OAUTH2_PROXY_WHITELIST_DOMAINS: '*'
      OAUTH2_PROXY_REVERSE_PROXY: 'true'
```

And here is my service with traefik labels:

```
      labels:
        - "traefik.enable=true"
        - "traefik.http.routers.auth_testing.rule=Host(`test.${HOST_ABBR}.domain.org`)"
        - "traefik.http.routers.auth_testing.entrypoints=websecure"
        - "traefik.http.routers.auth_testing.tls=true"
        - "traefik.http.routers.auth_testing.tls.certresolver=leresolver"
        #- "traefik.http.middlewares.auth_testing_auth.basicauth.users=${HOST_USER}:${HOST_HASHED_PASS}"
        #- "traefik.http.routers.auth_testing.middlewares=auth_testing_auth"
        - "traefik.http.routers.auth_testing.middlewares=oauth-signin,oauth"
        # Set up service
        - "traefik.http.services.auth_testing_svc.loadbalancer.server.port=5000"
        - "traefik.http.routers.auth_testing.service=auth_testing_svc"
```

Hope you can help, I have encountered this issue for a week and still checking it or suggest some places that I can put the debug code.

Thank you so much.

Comment: if you run `docker-compose config` are all the env variables replaced correctly, nothing missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow the Traefik in this server could not route requests to OAuth with HTTPS URL `https://oauth.${HOST_ABBR}.doamin.org/oauth2/auth`, so I tried with the internal request: `http://oauth:4185/oauth2/auth` and it works for me.

Replace this line

```
'traefik.http.middlewares.oauth.forwardauth.address=https://oauth.${HOST_ABBR}.mydomain.org/oauth2/auth'
```

By

```
 - 'traefik.http.middlewares.oauth.forwardauth.address=http://oauth:4185/oauth2/auth'
```